# Network drive between 2 computers with the same IP address

Tags: network

I have 2 computers that need to have the same IP address but would like for them to see the same newtork drive. Can someone help me with the configuration of the newtork? What do I need to do, what equipment do I need to have?

Comment: You can't have two computers with the same IP address.  It's like having two mobile phones with the same number.  The only way to make it work is to use Network Address Translation (NAT) for one of your computers.  We need to know more about your network -- what equipment do you already have?

Answer (score 1):

"2 computers that need to have the same IP address" won't work. No matter what you do, those two need *different* IP addresses, preferrably within the same subnet.

As Ron's pointed out, there's a workaround using NAT but it's very messy. It involves translating their IP address on the way over to the other computer so that they appear with a different address there.

If your "network drive" requires you to access it with a single, defined IP address only, you could hide both computers behind a much simpler NAT setup though:

Both computers would use different (internal) IP addresses on their side and get NATed to the same (external) IP address by the router. This is very much like you build a simple Internet access for IPv4.